# VS2010 The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#

I have a form with the Add button, as soon as I click on it I get this error message
here is the code for the add button

```
private void btnajoutemploye_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeControlleur ec = new EmployeControlleur();
        EmployeInfo ei = new EmployeInfo();
        bool result;

        ei.matricule = int.Parse(mat.Text);
        ei.nom = nom.Text;
        ei.prenom = pre.Text;
        ei.naissance = naiss.Text;
        ei.lieu = lieu.Text;
        ei.sexe = sex.Text;
        ei.situationfamille = stmat.Text;
        result = ec.ajoutemploye(ei);

        if (result == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Opération effectuée avec succès...");
            this.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur...");

        }
```

and the code of the methode

```
class EmployeControlleur
{
    public bool ajoutemploye(EmployeInfo  employe)
    {

        DataBaseHelper dh = new DataBaseHelper();

        dh.ExecuteNonQuery("Insert into Employe values (" + employe.matricule + ",'" + employe.nom + ",'" + employe.prenom + ",'"
            + employe.naissance + ",'" + employe.lieu + ",'" + employe.sexe + ",'" + employe.situationfamille + ",'"
            + employe.personnecontact + ")");
        return true;


    }


}
```

Can someone help me see more clearly?

I explain:
I create a class Employee Info and I used the ExecuteReader method which here is the code:

```
 class EmployeInfo
{
    private int Matricule;

    public int matricule
    {
        get { return Matricule; }
        set { Matricule = value; }
    }
    private string Nom;

    public string nom
    {
        get { return Nom; }
        set { Nom = value; }
    }
    private string Prenom;

    public string prenom
    {
        get { return Prenom; }
        set { Prenom = value; }
    }
    private string Date_naiss;

    public string naissance
    {
        get { return Date_naiss; }
        set { Date_naiss = value; }
    }
    private string lieu_naiss;

    public string lieu
    {
        get { return lieu_naiss; }
        set { lieu_naiss = value; }
    }
    private string Sexe;

    public string sexe
    {
        get { return Sexe; }
        set { Sexe = value; }
    }
    private string Situation_fam;

    public string situationfamille
    {
        get { return Situation_fam; }
        set { Situation_fam = value; }
    }
    private string Personnecontact;

    public string personnecontact
    {
        get { return Personnecontact; }
        set { Personnecontact = value; }
    }
    private int id_serv;

    public int idserv
    {
        get { return id_serv; }
        set { id_serv = value; }
    }
    private int id_statut;

    public int idstatut
    {
        get { return id_statut; }
        set { id_statut = value; }
    }

    public EmployeInfo()
    {
      }


    public EmployeInfo(int employe)
    {
        DataBaseHelper dh = new DataBaseHelper();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = dh.ExecuteReader("Select * from Employe where Matricule = "+employe);
        if (dr.Read())
        {

           matricule=dr.GetInt32(Matricule);
            nom=dr["Nom"].ToString();
           prenom=dr["Prenom"].ToString();
           naissance=dr["Date_naiss"].ToString();
           lieu=dr["Lieu_naiss"].ToString();
            sexe=dr["Sexe"].ToString();
           situationfamille=dr["Situation_fam"].ToString();
            personnecontact=dr["Personnecontact"].ToString();
           idserv=dr.GetInt32(id_serv);
            idstatut=dr.GetInt32(id_statut);

        }

        dr.Close();
    }
}
```

a second class Employee Controller with code:

```
 public bool ajoutemploye(EmployeInfo  employe)
    {

        DataBaseHelper dh = new DataBaseHelper();

        dh.ExecuteNonQuery("Insert into Employe values (" + employe.matricule + ",'" + employe.nom + ",'" + employe.prenom + ",'"
            + employe.naissance + ",'" + employe.lieu + ",'" + employe.sexe + ",'" + employe.situationfamille + ",'"
            + employe.personnecontact + ")");
        return true;
```

now in the form an Add button to save data and the button code above:

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use an ORM like Entity Framework or use command parameters.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: Also, what is the stack-trace of the `NotImplementedException` you're seeing? You haven't specified which code causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Should `btnajoutemploye_Click` be private or protected/internal? Shouldn't `EmployeControlleur` be internal or public? Not sure how your project is laid out. We need more detail...

Comment: When I clich Add button I get this message: The method or operation is not implemented  and also the MessageBox.Show after the If statement

Comment: If you comment out `this.close()` does the issue go away?

Answer (score 0):

"The method or operation is not implemented" is the default message of a `NotImplementedException` that is usually thrown explicitly in the code of a feature that is yet to be implemented.

A lot of automatically generated code uses this exception to indicate the places where you should put your own code. E.g. when I use Visual studio to automatically implement the methods of an interface, something like this is generated:

```
bool IMyInterface.MyMethod(string parameter)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The signature of the method is done for me, because it can be automatically inferred, but I will have to provide the body of the method.
So, take a look at the stack trace of your exception, to find out where your application expects code that you have not yet written.

---

Aside from that, the code for SQL generation is a horrible, wrong and unmaintainable mess. There is a lot of knowledge online (and mostly on Stack Overflow :)) of how to get it right - use it.